# Decoding a base64 encoded random on MinGW not working

Tags: bash, openssl, base64, mingw, git-bash

I am trying to make a bash script work on MinGW and it seems the shell is not able to decode something like the following.

```
t=$(openssl rand -base64 64)
echo "$t" | base64 --decode
```

Resulting in,

```
 Ԋ7▒%
     ▒7▒SUfX▒L:o<x▒▒䈏ţ94V▒▒▒▒uW;▒▒pxu▒base64: invalid input
```

Interestingly, if I output the base64 character and run the command as such, it works.

```
echo "+e5dcWsijZ83uR2cuKxIDJTTiwTvqB7J0EJ63paJdzGomQxw9BhfPvFTkdKP9I1o
g29pZKjUfDO8/SUNt+idWQ==" | base64 --decode
```

Anybody knows what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above case by passing `--ignore-garbage` flag to the base64 decode. It ignores the non-alphabet characters.

```
echo "$t" | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage
```

However, I would still like to know how did I create "garbage" ;) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what has happened here is the base64 string contains some embedded spaces, and that causes the actual "invalid input" w (and what you observe to as  garbage.)

The `openssl rand -base64 64` command introduces some newlines (not spaces), for example,

```sh
openssl rand -base64 64 > b64.txt
```

... then viewing the b64.txt file in an editor I see two separate lines

```
tPKqKPbH5LkGu13KR6zDdJOBpUGD4pAqS6wKGS32EOyJaK0AmTG4da3fDuOI4T+k
abInqlQcH5k7k9ZVEzv8FA==
```

... and this implies there is a newline character between the 'k' and 'a'

So the base64 string has this embedded newline.  The `base64 -d` can handle newlines (as demonstrated by your successful example), but, it cannot handle space char.

The newlines can get translated to spaces by some actions of the shell.  This is very likely happening by the `echo $t`  I.e. if `t` has newlines inside it, then echo will just replace then with single space.  Actually, how it behaves can depend on shell options, and type of string quotes, if any, applied.

To fix the command, we can remove the newline before piping to the `base64 -d` command.

One way to do that is to use `tr` command, e.g. the following works on Linux:

```
t=$(openssl rand -base64 64 | tr -d '\n')
echo $t | base64 -d
```

... or alternatively, remove the spaces, again using `tr`

```
t=$(openssl rand -base64 64)
echo $t | tr -d ' ' | base64 -d
```

Comment: I see. But wouldn't the new line character still be there when I am doing the `echo "...<new line>..." | base64 --decode" as well?

Comment: @Starx ... you'r right, I clarified answer, to highlight difference of newline & space character

Comment: Thanks for the update but I still get the same output on MinGW.